# How Can the First Ionization Energy of Helium be Accurately Calculated Using Basic Quantum Mechanics?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, quantum-chemistry

How Can the First Ionization Energy of Helium be Accurately Calculated Using Basic Quantum Mechanics?

There is [a book which summarizes the fairly accurate calculation of the First Ionization Energy of Helium](https://www.lulu.com/shop/stephen-elliott/magnetics-and-radially-symmetric-helium-bh/ebook/product-18npv8vz.html?q=stephen%20elliott%20helium&page=1&pageSize=4), but it would be nice to see if there is a more direct answer than the one calculated, that might have better accuracy even.

The experimental ionization energies for Hydrogen and Helium are given at this link: [Experimental Values of Ionization Energies](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Physical_Properties_of_Matter/Atomic_and_Molecular_Properties/Ionization_Energy/Ionization_Energies) and in [Table 3 in the linked Chemistry book here](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Physical_Properties_of_Matter/Atomic_and_Molecular_Properties/Ionization_Energy):

Table 3: Ionization Energies (kJ/mol)

| Element | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| H | 1312 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| He | 2372 | 5250 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Li | 520 | 7297 | 11810 |  |  |  |  |  |
| Be | 899 | 1757 | 14845 | 21000 |  |  |  |  |
| B | 800 | 2426 | 3659 | 25020 | 32820 |  |  |  |
| C | 1086 | 2352 | 4619 | 6221 | 37820 | 47260 |  |  |
| N | 1402 | 2855 | 4576 | 7473 | 9442 | 53250 | 64340 |  |
| O | 1314 | 3388 | 5296 | 7467 | 10987 | 13320 | 71320 | 84070 |
| F | 1680 | 3375 | 6045 | 8408 | 11020 | 15160 | 17860 | 92010 |
| Ne | 2080 | 3963 | 6130 | 9361 | 12180 | 15240 |  |  |
| Na | 496 | 4563 | 6913 | 9541 | 13350 | 16600 | 20113 | 25666 |
| Mg | 737 | 1450 | 7731 | 10545 | 13627 | 17995 | 21700 | 25662 |

Are these the most currently-accepted experimentally-confirmed values?

Now how can these energies be calculated using radially-symmetric basic Quantum Mechanics Theory accurately?

I have made [fairly accurate Helium ionization calculations at this link](https://www.lulu.com/shop/stephen-elliott/magnetics-and-radially-symmetric-helium-bh/ebook/product-18npv8vz.html?q=stephen%20elliott%20helium&page=1&pageSize=4).  What are other accurate approaches that use just the radially-symmetric Schrödinger wave equation, with a few small simplifications?

Comment: You should define what you mean by "accurate" in context of your post. As any quantum calculations of a three-body system are inaccurate, unless we put the inaccuracy threshold above their inaccuracies.

Comment: Note that using photos/screenshots of text instead of typing text itself is highly discouraged.  The image text content cannot be indexed nor searched for, nor can be reused in answers.  Specifically handwritten scripts can be difficult to decipher.  Consider  copy/pasting or rewriting of at least essential parts. 
// Optionally, here are formatting guides for [texts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and [formulas/equations/expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here).

Comment: @Poutnik I try to reference the picture as a link and a picture only in the case where the copy link option **produces an error and does not work **.  If the link to the picture works, I always use the link, whenever possible.  In these cases where I got an error message with the link option, I took a screenshot of the picture and posted a separate html link reference.  Also, the accuracy calculation is given in the online book link reference.

Comment: The point is, the question content policy focuses on questions being self-contained, with quoted or reproduced essential content. Links are provided rather just as the content origin reference, or for further reading. By other words, the question should make perfect sense without following any link. // Instead of table images, there are preferred tables created by SE Markdown or by MathJAx/LaTex  code. See e.g.  [SE meta -  tables](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support) // I think this your case is acceptable, just for future.

Comment: Is this an ad for your book?

Comment: @Buck Thorn : I do not make any money from this online version of the book.  At this point, I am trying to figure out how to apply its principles to explain the Periodic table beyond Hydrogen and Helium, call it Volume 2 versus the referenced Volume 1 of the problem (and solution).  I feel that the screening calculations need to be accurately made in order to understand the current problem more clearly.  So, as to be short, it is not an advertisement.  (I have not even bought the hard copy myself!)

Comment: Hello @Buck Thorn  :I thought about your feedback - the question being self-contained.   The calculations that I used were tedious - relying on College Calculus Integrals.   To not detract from the core of the answer (getting buried in the integrals), I was thinking that a separate reference was best.  The current version of the book that I downloaded, my calculated ionization energy for Helium was 22.1433 eV (2136.6417 $ \pu{kJ/Mol} $ ) conversion at https://www.unitsconverters.com/en/Ev/Particle-To-Kj/Mol/Utu-6180-6179 .  Then the accuracy is $ {(2372-2136.6417)}/2372*100 = $ +9.9% accurate.

Comment: Also, I asked, "Are these most now-accepted experimental values?" because I remember writing a separate reference (not published here for reference) where the comparison between the CRC value for the first ionization of Helium and the calculated version of the fist ionization of Helium was within some 0.3% of the 24.5874 eV experimental (Helium) from the [CRC link][ https://is.muni.cz/do/rect/el/estud/prif/js11/fyz_chem/web/podpora/ELECTRON_CONFIGURATION.pdf ].  Now, there is an ionization theory error of ${(24.5874-22.1433)}/{(24.5874)}*{(100 {%})} = 9.94% $ accuracy.  I need to re-calculate.

Comment: There is a long history of calculating two-electron atoms starting with Bethe and Salpeter's classic book. https://journals.aps.org/pra/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevA.98.012510 claims calculations of non-relativistic energy levels in He to 28 or more significant digits.

Comment: You also might be interested in https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.127.093001 and references therein.

Comment: *my calculated ionization energy for Helium was 22.1433 eV ((2136.6417 kJ/mol)*  -  I would turn down the valid digits for it to be taken seriously. I do not believe the model is so accurate.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to reach the experimental results by basic methods, the wave function corresponding to $He$ atom has no analytical expression. The numerical methods used do not often bare a significant scientific meaning. Trying to reach this experimental result is more or less a computational challenge. The expansion of the ground-state function in a minimal basis-set leads to an accurate description depending on a right choice of the basis functions for this expansion. We are more interested in the suitable basis functions for reducing the computational cost.

> The current version of the book that I downloaded, my calculated ionization energy for Helium was 22.1433 eV (2136.6417 kJ/Mol ) conversion at unitsconverters.com/en/Ev/Particle-To-Kj/Mol/Utu-6180-6179 . Then the accuracy is (2372−2136.6417)/2372∗100= +9.9% accurate

Assuming that your second ionization energy is given by the analytical formula of hydrogenic atoms $E_2 = \frac{Z^2}{2n^2}$ a.u. , your total energy, related to the first ionization energy $E_1=22.14$ eV will be $E_{tot} = -(E_1+E_2) = -76.54$ eV. This ground state energy is not accurate at all for a numerical method. [A variational method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helium_atom) applied considering $V_{ee}$ as a perturbation gives an analytical solution of $E_{tot} = - 77.7$ eV more accurate that your numerical result.